# What does GNU flex library libfl provide?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, gnu, bison, flex-lexer

I could compile a program from flex and bison generated files by

`cc lex.yy.c program.tab.c -o output`

and also by

`cc lex.yy.c program.tab.c -lfl -o output`

They both run smoothly and without any problem.

So what did `libfl` provide here? I tried to search the documentation but couldn't find a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.a
libmain.o:
0000000000000000 T main
                 U yylex
libyywrap.o:
0000000000000000 T yywrap
```

As you can see it provides functions `main` and `yywrap`, so you needn't define them.

Comment: So why isn't there a duplicate definition of `main` error from the linker? `T main` doesn't look like a weak symbol.

Comment: If you don't need the `main` symbol, the `libmain.o` doesn't get linked into your executable, and there is no the multiple definition error.

Comment: Strange. Where/how is it specified that `libmain.o` can just be dropped from the library if it clashes with something already in the program?

Comment: Aha! If I use  `-Wl,--whole-archive -lfl -Wl,--no-whole-archive` around it, then I get the multiple definitions errors. It seems to be a behavior of how the linker treats archives w.r.t. the executable. Objects providing symbols that are already satisfied (or providing only unneeded symbols) are simply dropped.  That wouldn't be the case if we explode the archive into `.o` files and present them individually at the command line (more or less like the `--whole-archive` behavior).

Comment: Yep. If an object file is listed in linker command explicitly, it gets linked into the executable unconditionally. If an object file is a part of a static library, it gets linked in only if it provides definitions for some undefined symbols.